# Can I use older stories of Vampire: The Masquerade with the 20th edition?

Tags: world-of-darkness, published-adventures, vampire-the-masquerade

I have been interested in Vampire for a few years but have just finally found some friends that would be willing to play such a game and came across older books for the game. As I have never played a roleplaying game and plan on being the game master, I would like to use some of the stories already made for the game.

I have heard that the 20th anniversary is the way to go when it comes to the core book, but it seems much easier to pick up the supplements for older versions and also there are just more supplements for the older versions.

Can I use those those stories with the new rules or will i have to buy an older book. I have right now Alien Hunger and Awakening: Diablerie Mexico.

Comment: *Diablerie Mexico* is, be warned, not very good.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Vampire The Masquerade 20th Anniversary is compatible with Revised Edition

To a lesser extent, V20 is also compatible with second edition and first edition.  This was the entire point of the 20th Anniversary editions; they consolidate many of the version differences down to a single book that most players will find useful no matter which edition they were used to.

The meta-plot books (the vast majority of source books) provide quite a bit of information that is fully compatible with V20 and, depending on what you want out of the books, may already be integrated into the core V20 book.  These books add to the setting and largely are intended to provide background for your own stories.

However, if you are intending to use old published adventures, you will be out of luck.  Not because they are incompatible with V20, but because, to a large extent, they do not exist; you own the only two that I am aware of.  The intent of the game designers for the World of Darkness products is that you are supposed to take their world and tell your own stories in it.

The vast majority of Vampire products, that are not core or rule books, detail the world-changing events and major players in large cities.  Unless you intend to play the named characters, the books will only serve to add spice to your game, and are completely optional - and more to the point, are very likely to be of disservice to you as a new ST.  These books focus less on your story because they are written under the assumption that you have experience with running a game and how to integrate the setting material they provide into your game; they assume you know what to include, what to ignore, and what to modify.

Of course, that is a moot point if you choose to play the named NPCs from the books; while I may not advise that, if that is something you and your group has fun with, more power to you.

Comment: +1 Also take note that V20 presents a multifaceted approach to the metaplot - you would need to recognise that metaplot in the published adventures and make sure your chosen (or, you know, default V20) state of things matches the book you're using. There is no one set way of dealing with metaplot in V20.

Comment: As an effort to improve this: the two books he mentions are pretty close to "dungeon crawls" — Alien Hunger is a 1e product produced by Atlas Games before the tropes of the WoD were firmed, and Diablerie: Mexico is seriously a bug hunt. For someone looking for bottled adventures, those are some relatively good choices.

Comment: @Jadasc I had to go back and check the books.  I remember them being a lot more metaplot heavy than they are.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Tritium21 You're welcome. "Alien Hunger" predates any kind of metaplot, and although there's a little bit of the Samuel Haight story in Diablerie: Mexico, the ties to what would eventually become the metaplot are very weak.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I continued searching after writing this question, but found little that could help me. I will probably use Alien Hunger for our first game and come up with my own for the second. I do find it interesting that the game never got any other story supplements, but I guess that just speaks to the differences between how players play Vampire compared to other RPGs.

Comment: @takeshi that's by design, really.  Vtm is about the characters and the politics of a city.  It's impossible for writers to know the politics of your table. The books you have are old... ancient really, from before the game found itself

Comment: Just to help others if they stumble upon this conversation and are looking for the same thing. After having seen the added tag of Published Adventures , I thought I would give a try to searching with that tag and Vtm because previously i was trying to look them up from the wording on the books. I came across a list of some other stories people might be interested in. I don't know how this site feels about hyperlinks but i will leave one and if  there is a problem with that i will just copy over the info. https://rpggeek.com/thread/828098/scenario-books

Comment: You might also want to check out the Chicago Chronicles, Ashes to Ashes and its sequel dust to dust.