# Is "Time Of Thin Blood" book from Revised edition fully compatible with V20?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Subject. 
Or are there any problems/changes in some V20 books? I have always been a fan of weak vampires, but I like V20 more than Revised.
I speak about mechanics rather than setting.

Comment: I think that [THIS](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82378/can-i-use-older-stories-of-vampire-the-masquerade-with-the-20th-edition/82384#82384) answer can be totally useful.

Comment: I speak about mechanics, not stories.

Comment: The other question is asking the same thing: “Can I use those those stories with the new rules”.